# SQL Server : have stored procedure return dataset and carry out comparison

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, comparison

I have created a stored procedure `QueryProductLines @ParamProductLineId Int`. This works fine and returns the results it should.

However, I now want to create an additional stored procedure `FindCommonProductLines @ParamProductLineIdOne INT, @ParamProductLineIdTwo` that will call the `QueryProductLines` stored procedure twice and carry out a comparison and return any common products.

For example:

- Product Line One:

  - Product A Product B Product C Product D Product E
- Product Line Two:

  - Product C, Product D, Product F, Product G

The stored procedure would return Product C and Product D (as they are common in both Product Lines).

Is this possible within a stored procedure only? Any outline of how this could be achieved would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My apologies, done.

Comment: Any particular reason you want `FindCommonProductLines` to call `QueryProductLines` and not just perform the query directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to call the existing stored procedure for each product line using `INSERT...EXEC` to capture the results of each into a temp table/variable. The table/variable schema must match that of the `QueryProductLines` result set, although you can ignore unneeded columns in the final query.

Below is an example of this technique.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FindCommonProductLines
      @ParamProductLineIdOne int
    , @ParamProductLineIdTwo int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ProductLineIdOne TABLE(
    ProductName varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY
);
DECLARE @ProductLineIdTwo TABLE(
    ProductName varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO @ProductLineIdOne(ProductName)
    EXEC dbo.QueryProductLines @ParamProductLineId = @ParamProductLineIdOne;
INSERT INTO @ProductLineIdTwo(ProductName)
    EXEC dbo.QueryProductLines @ParamProductLineId = @ParamProductLineIdTwo;

SELECT p1.ProductName
FROM @ProductLineIdOne AS p1
JOIN @ProductLineIdTwo AS p2 ON p2.ProductName = p1.ProductName;
GO
```

From a performance perspective, but at the expense of code reuse, it would be more efficient to develop a specialized query to return the common products.